# Tornado - What is the difference between RequestHandler's get_argument(), get_query_argument() and get_body_argument()?

Tags: python, http-headers, tornado, httpresponse, http-request

When to use **`RequestHandler.get_argument()`**, **`RequestHandler.get_query_argument()`** and **`RequestHandler.get_body_argument()`**?

What is the ***use-case*** for each of them?

Also what does the `request.body` and `request.argument` do in these cases? Which are to be used in which scenarios?

And, is there a `request.query` or something similar too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most HTTP requests store extra parameters (say, form values) in one of two places: the URL (in the form of a [`?foo=bar&spam=eggs` query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)), or in the request body (when using a [POST request and either the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` mime type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms)).

The `Request.get_query_argument()` looks for URL parameters, the `RequestHandler.get_body_argument()` lets you retrieve parameters set in the POST body. The `RequestHandler.get_argument()` method retrieves either a body or a URL parameter (in that order).

You use `Request.get_argument()` when you explicitly don't care where the parameter comes from and your endpoint supports both GET and POST parameters. Otherwise, use one of the other methods, to keep it explicit where your parameters come from.

The `Request.get_*_argument` methods use the `request.body_arguments` and `request.query_arguments` values (with `request.arguments` being their aggregate), decoded to Unicode. `request.body` is the undecoded, unparsed raw request body; and yes, there is an equivalent `self.query` containing the query string from the URL.

Comment: @martin-pieters Thanks Martin. What about the second part? what is the difference between request.body and request.argument? and is there any request.query?

Comment: @AnirbanRoyDas: sorry, missed that, added now.

Comment: Finally got it. I have added another question, if you find time then please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821740/http-setting-content-type-of-request-or-response-header-to-application-json

Comment: This answer should just be copied to the documentation! Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Does tornado parse JSON format body with `get_body_argument()`? and what's the difference with `get_*_argument()` and `get_*_arguments()`?

Comment: @JasonXie there is no JSON support, no. Query and POST parameters can appear multiple times (`foo=42&foo=81`); `get_*_arguments()` returns a list with all values for a given parameter, `get_*_argument()` returns just the last value if there are is more than one.

Comment: Wow, that was not obvious at all from the docs I was reading, so thanks for this. If only query arguments had a less generic name.