# Tornado: get request arguments

Tags: python, json, tornado

I have following code:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/get(.*)", GetHandler),
])

class GetHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, key):
        response = {'key': key}
        self.write(response)
```

when I go to `localhost:port/get?key=python` I receive empty key value `{'key': ''}`. What is wrong here?

Comment: Check this out, it should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819282/3188346

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(.*)` in regex matches everything. So this — `(r"/get(.*)", GetHandler)` — will match anything followed by `/get`, example:

```
/get
/getsomething
/get/something
/get.asldfkj%5E&(*&fkasljf
```

Let's say a request comes in at `localhost:port/get/something`, then the value of `key` argument in `GetHandler.get(self, key)` will be `/something` (yes, including the slash because `.*` matches everything).

But if a request comes in at `localhost:port/get?key=python`, the value of `key` argument in `GETHandler.get(self, key)` will be an empty string. It happens because the part containing `?key=python` is called a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). It's not part of the url *path*. Tornado (or almost every other web framework) doesn't pass this to the view as an argument.

---

There are two ways you can change your code:

1. If you want to access your view like this - `localhost:port/get?key=python`, you'll need to make changes to your url config and to your view:

   ```
   application = tornado.web.Application([
       (r"/get", GetHandler),
   ])

   class GetHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
       def get(self):
           key = self.get_argument('key', None)
           response = {'key': key}
           self.write(response)
   ```
2. If you don't want to change your app url config and your view, you'll need to make the request like this - `localhost:port/get/python`.
   But still you'll need to make a small change to your url config. Add a slash - `/` - between `get` and `(.*)`, because otherwise the value of key would be `/python` instead of `python`.

   ```
   application = tornado.web.Application([
       (r"/get/(.*)", GetHandler), # note the slash
   ])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

*I hope that you will figure what you did wrong by yourself - that's a task for you.*

Your working code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class GetHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        response = self.get_arguments("key")
        if len(response) == 0:
            # Handle me
            self.set_status(400)
            return self.finish("Invalid key")
        self.write({"key":self.get_argument("key")})


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", GetHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```